# Mandrill problem with sending emails: Message not sent: queued

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill

I have an issue with using Mandrill to send emails, I created an account and a new template but when I try to send a test of that template ... I get the following message even I had ever send an email.

> " Message not sent: queued "

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it for whose who have the same pb , i sent an email to Mandrill support `help@mandrill.com` and they fixed it this is there replay:

> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for reaching out. Your account matched some of our automated
>   abuse detection heuristics and was paused temporarily for review.
>   We've re-enabled your account and your mail is beginning to send. Let
>   us know if you have any additional questions or concerns.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do they manually have to enable every account before we are allowed to send?

Comment: @Pedram  some accounts are paused automatically and it seems that when you contact them they check your account and reactivate it manually ...

Answer (score 0):

Emails will also be queued if they include an attachment. As such, if you're using the API, the async flag will be ignored.

> Messages that include attachments will be queued and the attachments processed through a series of virus scanning engines to help ensure that the attachments are safe for recipients.

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582407-Does-Mandrill-support-attachments-